# Do something specific if PC name matches PC name in a AD Group

Tags: powershell

I have no idea where to even start with this, so I am not necessarily looking for an exact answer, but any tips or assistance is appreciated!

I would like to compare the name of the PC I am running the Powershell script from against a group in AD. If the PC name matches the name of a PC in the group, I want it to write a specific file to a folder.

I know how to do parts individually such as write files to folders and lookup which PC I am on. I can get Powershell to return results against that group, for example, GetProcess

```
$ComputerName = Hostname
$ADGroup = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TagTest

foreach ($Computer in $ADGroup) {
Get-Process }
```

But can't work out how to only do that if the PC I am on matches one in the group.

Comment: I hope I get youre question right...`if($ADGroup -contains $ComputerName) { Out-file -FilePath .\yourfile.txt -InputObject $ComputerName}`

Comment: I think that's what I needed! Didn't realise there was a -contains. Let me play and come back!

Comment: I think that will work, but, `Get-AdGroupMember -Identity TagTest` returns the details of each computer in the group and I beleive it uses the distinguishedName, not the name.

Is there anyway to specify for it to use just the name?

Comment: Maybe `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`. I can't test atm, so either you show the output or I have to guess

Comment: We got there :)

I changed it a little, but the end result is this and it works!

`$ComputerName = Hostname
$ADGroup = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TagTest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Source = 'C:\Temp\Test Doc.txt'

if($ADGroup -contains $ComputerName) { 
Copy-Item $source -Destination C:\Temp2\}`

Comment: Don't post it as a comment, thats what Answers are there for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ComputerName = Hostname
$ADGroup = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TagTest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
$Source = 'C:\Temp\Test Doc.txt' if($ADGroup -contains $ComputerName) { Copy-Item 
$source -Destination C:\Temp2\}`
```

Thanks to Paxz in the comments.